# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in field list

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

i have 3 forms in one page using `ajax` for them. Edit form is getting error as below. I dont know why i am getting this error. **I am beginner**.
error while submitting form:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `user_profiles` set `0` = , `updated_at` = 2018-08-18 10:25:43 where `id` = 1)"

**This is my edit button code:**

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editExchangeMarket({{$user_profiles->id}});">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
</a>
```

This is my modal and ajax code:

```js
<script>
        function updateExchangeMarket() {
            var edit_fid = $('#edit_fid').val();
            var edit_charge_per_lot = $('#edit_charge_per_lot').val();
            $('#exchangeMarketModal').modal('show');
            //   alert(values);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                url: "{{URL::to('user/updateExchangeMarket')}}",
                data:{'id' : edit_fid, 'edit_charge_per_lot':edit_charge_per_lot},
                method:'POST',
                success: function( resp ) {
                    },
                error: function( req, status, err ) {
                console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
                    }
            });

        }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="exchangeMarketModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="exchangeMarketForm" name="exchangeMarketForm" >
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="edit_fid" value="1">

                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 form-group">
                        chargeperlot: <input type="text" name="edit_charge_per_lot" id="edit_charge_per_lot" class="form-control"><br>
                    </div>
               
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <a type="submit" href="javascript:void(1);" onclick="updateExchangeMarket({{$user_profiles->id}});" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now i am adding here my controller code:

```
        public function updateExchangeMarket(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;    
        $charge_per_lot = $request->edit_charge_per_lot;

        $data = array('country_id'=>$country_id,
            'id'=>$id,
            'charge_per_lot'=>$charge_per_lot,

        );
        $res = UserProfile::where('id',$id)->update([$data]);
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UserProfile::where('id',$id)->update(
[
  'name' => $name,
  'number' => $number
]);
```

by this way you can do query if you have mutiple parameters & values to query

Comment: its updating only on column

Comment: if i added 5 records and i trying to edit, 4rth but its not working 4rth  but it do something another from 5.

Comment: its not actually error but, its updating different column,

Comment: show me database table which you are tring to edit .code also to update

Answer (score 3):

Update() takes an assocative array to update the values. your `$data` is already an associative array so no need to push it as an array.

```
$data = array('country_id'=>$country_id,
            'id'=>$id,
            'charge_per_lot'=>$charge_per_lot,

        );
        $res = UserProfile::where('id',$id)->update($data)
```